# Why do I get NoSuchMethodError: main in my Applet?

Tags: java, applet, program-entry-point

I need help in my Java applet.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class Screen extends Applet{
    public void init(){
        setSize(300,300);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    }
}
```

This error keeps popping up when I run it.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main
```

Comment: It's an Applet, not an application; obviously, there is no `main` method unless you've written one.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to run the applet as an application using

`java Screen`

That won't work, because an applet is not an application, and doesn't normally have a `main()` method, which is what `java Screen` will try to run.

There are a few solutions:

1. Run it using the `appletviewer` tool, which comes with the JDK.
2. Run it in the browser by embedding it in an HTML page.
3. Make it an "app-applet".

It's been almost ten years since I've actually written an applet so I don't remember the details around #3, but IIRC it involves adding a `main()` method to the applet and having that `main()` method launch the applet. I'm sure you can find it on Google.

Comment: how do you make it an App-Applet

Comment: Just in passing applets really aren't the most common way to disseminate java apps at this point in time (honestly haven't been for a decade.) You may want to look into ASes that provide Java Web Start or similar...

Answer (score 3):

Create a new swing form. Since your class extends the default 'applet' you can simply add it to a swing application like this `Screen x = new Screen();` then add it to your JFrame `YourJframe.add(x);` Hope this helped! (I could use an upvote lol :))

Comment: at least click the little check mark below my votes, that chooses my answer as the best answer! It will also let people know that this question has been answered correctly